# How to process PDFs in-memory using python?

Tags: python, pdf, in-memory, pypdf

**Background:**

I have a PDF file with multiple pages (`LARGE_PDF`). Every page contains one table and no other content. Every table looks different. I want to extract the table contents and put them to a pandas dataframe. I am using [tabula-py](https://pypi.org/project/tabula-py/0.3.0/) for that and it works as desired with the below approach:

**Approach:**

First, I split the PDF file to multiple single-page PDF files and save them to disc.

```
single_page_files = split_and_save(LARGE_PDF) # Split to single files, one page each
```

Second, feed every single file to tabula-py.

```
from tabula import read_pdf as tabular_read 

for item in single_page_files:                
    print type(item)
    df = tabular_read(PDF_page, pandas_options={'header':None})
    if df:
         print 'approach works'
```

Output:

```
>>> <type 'str'>                              # filepath string
>>> approach works
```

**Challenge:**

I now want to do this in-memory, so that no intermediate single-page pdf files are saved to disk. In order to do this, I create a list of single-page `PyPDF2.pdf.PageObject` objects and feed them to tabula-py.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

single_page_pypdfobjects = split_but_dont_save(LARGE_PDF)
for item in single_page_pypdfobjects:                
    print type(item)
    df = tabular_read(PDF_page, pandas_options={'header':None})
    if df:
         print 'approach works'
```

Output:

```
>>> class 'PyPDF2.pdf.PageObject'>             # PyPDF2 single page object
>>> TypeError: unhashable type
```

**How to process PDFs in-memory using python?**

Comment: just take a look  [here](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/07/16/pypdf-how-to-write-a-pdf-to-memory/).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to split up the PDF. [Tabla-py](https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py) has an option `pages` to tell it what pages you want to extract from.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am aware of that option. Due to various reason, I need to split. I can't change this approach.

Comment: Then you must use temporary files as Tabla doesn't support taking anything else as input. Well it does support file like objects but internally it handles them by writing them to a file.

Comment: I am surprised. I did not find anything in the docs about that. What about StringIO objects or something similar?

Comment: `read_pdf` calls `localize_file` which handles file-like objects and URL by fetching them and copying then to a file.